# How do I conditionally bind in a do block?

Tags: haskell, conditional-statements, bind, monads, do-notation

I want to achieve the following in a do block:

```
do 
  if condition then
    n0 <- expr0
  else
    n0 <- expr0'
  n1 <- expr1
  n2 <- expr2
  return T n0 n1 n2
```

But Haskell gives a compile error unless I do:

```
do 
  if condition then
    n0 <- expr0
    n1 <- expr1
    n2 <- expr2
    return T n0 n1 n2  
  else
    n0 <- expr0'
    n1 <- expr1
    n2 <- expr2
    return T n0 n1 n2
```

It looks very verbose, especially when there are many shared binding expressions. How do I make it more concise?

Actually, I am trying to do the following:

```
do 
  if isJust maybeVar then
    n0 <- f (fromJust maybeVar)
    n1 <- expr1
    n2 <- expr2
    return (T (Just n0) n1 n2)
  else
    n1 <- expr1
    n2 <- expr2
    return (T Nothing n1 n2)
```

The following still fails to compile:

```
do 
  n0 <- if isJust maybeVar then Just (f (fromJust maybeVar)) else Nothing
  n1 <- expr1
  n2 <- expr2
  return (T n0 n1 n2)
```

Comment: You wrote `if ... then ... then`, not `if ... then ... else`.

Comment: `if isJust maybeVar then Just (f (fromJust maybeVar)) else Nothing` is much better spelled `f <$> maybeVar`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can "*inline*" the condition:

```
do 
  n0 <- if condition then expr0 else expr0'
  n1 <- expr1
  n2 <- expr2
  return (T n0 n1 n2)
```

You likely should use brackets in the `return` expression, so `return (T n0 n1 n2)`.

You can then rewrite the expression with [**`liftM3 :: Monad m => (a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m a3 -> m r`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM3) to:

```
liftM3 T (if condition then expr0 else expr0') expr1 expr2
```

Since Haskell is a pure language evaluating expressions has no side-effects. But here the `if`...`then`...`else` will at most evaluate one of the two expression. An `IO a` itself has no side-effects either, since it is a "recipe" to generate an `a`.

**EDIT**: For your second example, it is more complicated.

```
do 
    n0 <- if isJust maybeVar then Just <$> (f (fromJust maybeVar)) else pure Nothing
    n1 <- expr1
    n2 <- expr2
    return (T n0 n1 n2)
```

So here we use `pure Nothing` to "wrap" `Nothing` in the monadic context, and `Just <$>` to apply `Just` on the value(s) inside the monadic context.

Or as [@luqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57748720/how-to-conditionally-bind-in-do-block/57748736?noredirect=1#comment101936511_57748736) says, we can here use [**`traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:traverse):

```
do 
    n0 <- traverse f maybeVar
    n1 <- expr1
    n2 <- expr2
    return (T n0 n1 n2)
```

This works since a `Maybe` is traversable: for a `Just` we traverse the single element, for `Nothing` it will return `Nothing`.

Comment: I added more context to be more precise. Please advise on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: U just made my day. I still have to think more on why your solution works, but it definitely works like a charm!

Comment: “due to Haskell's laziness” – that's a bit of a red herring. Even if they were _evaluated_ eagerly, that still wouldn't mean they would be _executed_ as well.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: yes I agree. I rewrote that part.

Comment: BTW the second example can be written `n0 <- traverse f maybeVar` (though I like that you showed it the way you did for pedagogical reasons)

Answer (score 5):

Since the OP says "I still have to think more on why your solution works" in a comment, I thought I would add some explanation as a complementary answer.

Haskell's `if condition then x else y` syntax is actually *not* an analogue for the standard if/then/else statement seen in almost every imperative language. It is much more closely analogous to conditional expression syntax (seen in C as `condition ? x : y`, or in Python as `x if condition else y`). Once you remember that, everything else about it follows naturally.

`if condition then x else y` in Haskell is an expression for a **value**, not a **statement**. `x` and `y` are not "things to do" based on whether `condition` is true or not, but simply 2 different values; the whole if/then/else expression is a value that is either equivalent to `x` or equivalent to `y` (depending on the condition).

So with that in mind, lets take a look at the working version suggested by Willem Van Onsem:

```
do 
  n0 <- if condition then expr0 else expr0'
  n1 <- expr1
  n2 <- expr2
  return (T n0 n1 n2)
```

Here the `if condition then expr0 else expr0'` is entirely on the right hand side of a single `<-` statement. So it's an expression for a value, just like `expr1` and `expr2` are on the following lines. It doesn't say to either bind `n0` from `expr0` or bind `n0` from `expr0'`, it just **is** either `expr0` or `expr0'`. The `<-` statement that contains the if/then/else is what says to bind `n0`, and it binds it *unconditionally* from the *single* value computed by the whole if/then/else.

We can easily see this by the fact that we could declare a top-level variable equal to the if/then/else totally independently of the do block (assuming that `condition`, `expr0`, and `expr0'` are globally available) and replace the if/then/else by a reference to this variable.

```
foo = do 
  n0 <- z
  n1 <- expr1
  n2 <- expr2
  return (T n0 n1 n2)

z = if condition then expr0 else expr0'
```

Here it's very clear that the if/then/else has nothing at all to do with the binding of `n0` in the do block.

Let's compare that to the original non-working version:

```
do 
  if condition then
    n0 <- expr0
  else
    n0 <- expr0'
  n1 <- expr1
  n2 <- expr2
  return (T n0 n1 n2)
```

This is using an if/then/else with **statements** as the then and else parts. Instead of just "being" one value or another, this is saying to "do" one thing or another. That's not how Haskell's if/then/else works. The whole if/then/else needs to be able to be understood as an expression for a single value.

Again this should be clear if we imagine trying to factor out the if/then/else into a separate declaration:

```
foo = do
  z
  n1 <- expr1
  n2 <- expr2
  return (T n0 n1 n2)

z = if condition then
      n0 <- expr0
    else
      n0 <- expr0'
```

It should be clear that this doesn't make any sense. The then and else parts aren't independent value-expressions, they only make sense inside a do block. And they need to be inside the *particular* do block in `foo`, so that `n0` is bound for later use in `return (T n0 n1 n2)`.

Since the statements of do blocks are transformed into expressions anyway, you might think that putting statements as the then/else parts of an if expression *should* work. However the transformation of do blocks into expressions "cuts across" statements, so this doesn't work. For example this:

```
do  n <- expr
    rest
```

is equivalent to this:

```
expr >>= (\n -> rest)
```

I won't get into a full technical explanation of that if you don't already understand it, but hopefully you can see that the `n` ends up more closely connected to `rest` than it does with the `expr` it was bound from in the statement (`rest` represents the entire remaining contents of the do block, in more complicated examples). There is no single expression that represents just the `n <- expr` part, which you could put inside the then or else part of an if/then/else expression.